# Python. I get "socket.error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address" after opening and closing many sockets on client side?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Client side code:

```
for currentFile in files:
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))
    f = open(currentFile, 'rb')
    b = f.read()
    while b:
        s.send(b)
        b = f.read()
    s.close()
    f.close()
```

Server side code:

```
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serverSocket.listen(1)
while True:
    (clientsocket, address) = serverSocket.accept()
    b = clientsocket.recv(4096)
    f = open('filename', 'wb')
    while b:
        f.write(b)
        b = clientsocket.recv(4096)
    f.close()
```

My actual server side code has a bit more to it, but it has nothing to do with the networking part (Generating filename for each new file etc)

When I send a lot of files over a relatively short amount of time, I this error
`socket.error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address`

I modified my code with a try except block:

```
notFoundSocket = 1
while notFoundSocket:
    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
        notFoundSocket=0
    except:
        print "Error"
```

In which case it prints out "Error" for a while, and then it continues on sending the files. So it seems to me that the port I establish between my client and server is not released immediately, and I have to wait a while after I close it until I can use it again. Could this be correct? And if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: It looks like you ran out of available ports. Is "a lot of files". How many sockets did you actually open?

Comment: I'm trying to send about 91 000 files, and I'm getting the error after I've sent about 30% of the total size of all the files

Comment: At this point I guess you have 28,000 sockets in closing state still in the OS. It has a limit on the number of sockets. The sockets will clean up after a while. For testing: count the iteration and add a `sleep(30)` every 10,000.

Comment: You are correct, with adding a sleep after a number of sockets it does fix the problem. Would that be a more preferable approach than the try except block I had in my original post? And after counting the sockets I got 16392 before the error occured

Comment: Considering that the `try` / `except` will always run up to the maximum number of available sockets, it will also block other applications you trying to open a socket. A well tuned `sleep` call will prevent that.

Comment: That's is a good point, thx. I guess I have a choice of either using a sleep call or sending all the data over the same socket. If you'd post your comment as an answer I'll accept it and close the question :)